# an hour ago vs in an hour ago

Tags: vocabulary

> “I left it on a subway train an hour ago.” ([its audio](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/465))

This is the sentence that I took a dictation. But there seems to be a mismatch between the script and its audio. I hear ***in*** an hour ago instead of *an hour ago*. Now, what I wanted to know is if I hear well, first. And second, if both expressions, *an hour ago* and *in an hour ago*, can be used without meaning difference.

Comment: What you have written makes sense. The audio file does appear to be saying "I left it on a subway train in a hour ago," but that doesn't sound like proper English, unless there is some sort of time-travel involved.

Comment: I think this is a hyper-articulation (possibly a stumble, but probably just trying to be super precise) at the train/an junction. But good catch.

Comment: @StoneyB, Yes, I (think I) hear the way you say. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think it's saying "in an hour ago", but there seems to be an additional vowel appended to "an", making it sound more like "an-uh", and we're filling in the gaps. Also, it's an unusually high vowel, closer to "in" than "an", so it sounds like "in-uh".

Comment: See CGEL p.632, where they analyse *ago* as a (rather exceptional) preposition which always follows its complement.  Looking at it this way, it's easy to see why the PP \*[ **in** an hour **ago** ] is strange—it's got two heads!  It should only have one.

Comment: @snailplane, It’s very wonderful to have here experts to lead to those wonderful visions. I started the book almost a year ago by them, now reading p.384. It may still take at least more than three and half year to read once, but it’s very worth to read on. Thank you.)

Comment: @jimsug, Yes! you’ve embodied the sound much better clear to me. I didn’t hear “n” after “an-uh”. That’s why I was confused. Thank you, who are an expert using sound-analysing tools. I’ve searched the one who, like you, once gave me the analysis and caused Mr.@StoneyB couldn’t stop gaping at it, but sadly I can’t find his.

Comment: @jimsug I think if we tried to explain this sound as "an-uh", where this "an" is a variant of schwa, an unusually high vowel one, we might have a problem trying to explain another sound in the clip, "it". The "in" is even higher (it's more like a clear /i/ sound) than the "it".

Comment: @DamkerngT. The thing is, it's definitely _not_ "in an" - there's no /n/ after the "in-a". Also, the additional vowel sound may be a result of the speaker articulating the glottal stop at the beginning of "hour", where most speakers would just liaise the two words and omit that.

Comment: @jimsug I've notice that too, which is why I don't know how to explain this "[i(a)n]-uh" as something not a mispronunciation. (I tried placing the "it" next to the "i(a)n-uh" to try to understand her sounds.) My guess, which I think it's a fair guess, is that, she planned to pronounce "an hour" very clearly, maybe for ELLs, but pronouncing it as "an-hour" instead of "uhnour" wasn't what she usually does, so the first part "i(a)n" came out not quite right, she heard it and tried to fix it, but it was too late, so we got two syllables "i(a)n-uh" instead of one "uhn". It's just a guess though.

Comment: I'd be prepared to bet any money the speaker is ***not a native speaker***. In principle she might "know" what she should have said - but because it's not her own language, she can make mistakes without necessarily realising. I think it's General Reference that if you want to study a foreign language this precisely, you should stick to ***native speaker examples***.

Comment: Closevoter: I don't think this is **General Reference**, since language learners aren't usually in a position to judge whether people are native speakers or not. However, this is almost an aural **proofreading** question.

Comment: @jimsug Indeed, in terms of topicality, this is extremely close to [this](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1033/temporarily-attached-files).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, I agree it does sound weird. As @StoneyB said, she is definitely trying to over-pronounce the words for clarity (though clearly unsuccessfully).

No, "in an hour ago" doesn't make sense.